# SharePoint 2019 - Access Denied to all permissions after setting up a search center

Tags: access-denied

I have just setup SharePoint 2019 on-prem with the min-role topology.  I created a web application and a site collection.  I added users to the site.  I needed to create a search center.  I created a new site collection for the search center.  After setting it up, I get "Sorry, you don't have access to site permissions and any library or list permissions on anything within the web application.

Has anyone experienced this?  Does anyone have a suggestion?

I set my logging to verbose, 
ULS on my Web Front End

```
PortalSiteMapProvider was unable to fetch current node, request URL: /_layouts/15/user.aspx, message: Thread was being aborted., stack trace:
    at System.Threading.Thread.AbortInternal() 
    at System.Threading.Thread.Abort(Object stateInfo) 
    at System.Web.HttpResponse.AbortCurrentThread() 
    at System.Web.HttpResponse.Redirect(String url, Boolean endResponse, Boolean permanent) 
    at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPUtility.Redirect(String url, SPRedirectFlags flags, HttpContext context, String queryString) 
    at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPUtility.RedirectToAccessDeniedPage(HttpContext context) 
    at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPUtility.HandleAccessDenied(HttpContext context, Exception exception, Boolean allowCompleteRequest) 
    at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPUtility.HandleAccessDenied(Exception ex) 
    at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.OpenWeb(String bstrUrl, StorePath path, StorePath& pspServerRelativeUrl, String& pbstrTitle, String& pbstrDescription, String& pbstrTitleResourceId, String& pbstrDescriptionResourceId, Guid& pguidID, DateTime& pdtTimeCreated, String& pbstrRequestAccessEmail, UInt32& pwebVersion, Guid& pguidScopeId, UInt32& pnAuthorID, UInt32& pnLanguage, UInt32& pnLocale, UInt16& pnTimeZone, Boolean& bTime24, Int16& pnCollation, UInt32& pnCollationLCID, Int16& pnCalendarType, Int16& pnAdjustHijriDays, Int16& pnAltCalendarType, Boolean& pbShowWeeks, Int16& pnFirstWeekOfYear, UInt32& pnFirstDayOfWeek, Int16& pnWorkDays, Int16& pnWorkDayStartHour, Int16& pnWorkDayEndHour, Int16& pnMeetingCount, Int32& plFlags, Boolean& bConnectedToPortal, String& pbstrPortalUrl, String& pbstrPortalName, Int32& plWebTemplateId, Int16& pnProvisionConfig, String& pbstrDefaultTheme, String& pbstrDefaultThemeCSSUrl, StorePath& pspThemedCssFolderUrl, String& pbstrAlternateCSSUrl, String& pbstrCustomizedCssFileList, String& pbstrCustomJSUrl, String& pbstrAlternateHeaderUrl, StorePath& pspMasterUrl, StorePath& pspCustomMasterUrl, String& pbstrSiteLogoUrl, String& pbstrSiteLogoDescription, Object& pvarUser, Boolean& pvarIsAuditor, UInt64& ppermMask, Boolean& bUserIsSiteAdmin, Boolean& bHasUniquePerm, Guid& pguidUserInfoListID, Guid& pguidUniqueNavParent, Int32& plSiteFlags, DateTime& pdtLastContentChange, DateTime& pdtLastSecurityChange, StorePath& pspWelcomePagePath, String& pbstrWelcomePageParameters, Boolean& pbOverwriteMUICultures, Boolean& pbMUIEnabled, String& pbstrAlternateMUICultures, Int32& plSiteSchemaMajorVersion, Int32& plSiteSchemaMinorVersion, Int32& plSiteSchemaBuildVersion, Int32& plSiteSchemaRevisionVersion, Int32& puiVersion, Int16& pnClientTag, Boolean& pfIsEvalSite, Guid& pgSourceSiteId, DateTime& pdtExpirationDate, Guid& pgEvalSiteId, Guid& pguidAppProductId, String& pbstrRemoteAppUrl, String& pbstrOAuthAppId, String& pbstrAppDatabaseName, Guid& pgAppDatabaseServerReferenceId, String& pbstrAppDatabaseTargetApplicationId, String& pbstrAppDatabaseLastAccessedDate, Int32& pnAppDatabaseStorageState, String& pbstrAppWebDomainId, Int32& plUpgradeFlags, DateTime& pdtReminderDate, UInt64& pmaskDeny, Int64& pllDiskQuota, Int64& pllDiskUsed, Int64& pllDiskWarning, UInt32& pulminutesSinceDenyMaskUpdate, String& pbstrDenyMaskGroupId, UInt64& pulCacheFlags, Int32& pminCacheAge, Int32& plRootWebTemplateId, Int64& pllSiteFlags2, Int32& plRefreshActionAge, Guid& pgGroupId, String& pbstrSiteClassification, Guid& pgSubscriptionIdDB, Guid& pgDesignPackageId, String& pbstrComplianceAttribute, Int64& pllFlags2, Guid& pgDepartmentId, Boolean& pfIsSiteKeyEnabled, String& pbstrSharingProperties) 
    at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.InitWeb() 
    at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.get_Title() 
    at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite.OpenWeb(Guid gWebId, Int32 mondoHint) 
    at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.CachedObjectFactory.OpenWebFromSuperUserSite(Guid webId) 
    at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.CacheManager..ctor(SPSite site) 
    at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.CacheManager.GetManager(SPSite site, Boolean useContextSite, Boolean allowContextSiteOptimization, Boolean refreshIfNoContext) 
    at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Navigation.PortalSiteMapProvider.get_ObjectFactory() 
    at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Navigation.PortalSiteMapProvider.get_TryGetCurrentNode()
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out.  I removed the super user and super reader accounts from the user policy of the web application.  I then re-added them and ran the following:

$wa = Get-SPWebApplication -Identity "http://blahblah.com"
$wa.Properties["portalsuperuseraccount"] = "domain\superuser"
$wa.Properties["portalsuperreaderaccount"] = "domain\superreader"
$wa.Update()